# I have received a reply from a potential professor. Is this a positive one?

Tags: phd

I am applying for a PhD position. The potential professor replied to me as below. Was it a positive one? I tried to arrange an informal interview with her but was rejected. I really like this position but, in my opinion, her reply was ambiguous.

"Thank you for sending your application. Your profile looks interesting. We are currently selecting candidates so I will add your application to the pool of applicants.

We hope to reach a final decision end of April. I will recontact you shortly after."

Edit: She told me the shortlist would come in mid-April, so I won't wait a long time LOL. It's time to apply for other positions!

Comment: It kind of reminds me of the classic "cannot recommend him too highly."

Comment: There is no clear subtext in this message. Read it at face value - you are not obviously unqualified, you are considered for the position, how far up in the list you are you will learn once they made their decision in a month.

Answer (score 5):

Her reply was neutral, neither positive nor negative. She probably hasn't made a serious attempt to evaluate your qualifications yet, and she is implicitly asking you to refrain from further contact for the time being.

My advice would be to wait, and not press the matter further until you hear from her again. In the meantime, you may want to apply for additional PhD positions.